# Не стартует Apache на CantOS8

Tags: linux, apache, centos, httpd

Не стартует Apache на CentOS 8...

#systemctl status httpd

```
 httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-10-21 11:28:45 EDT; 1min 0s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 27606 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 27606 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."

Oct 21 11:28:45 web.chipman.local systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 21 11:28:45 web.chipman.local httpd[27606]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Oct 21 11:28:45 web.chipman.local httpd[27606]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Oct 21 11:28:45 web.chipman.local systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 21 11:28:45 web.chipman.local systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 21 11:28:45 web.chipman.local systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/web.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName web.chipman.local
    ServerAlias www.web.chipman.local
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/site1

    ErrorLog /srv/www/logs/errors.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/logs/access.log common

    <Directory /srv/www/site1>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Подскажите в чём проблема и как решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Апач не слушает никакой порт. Добавим строчку `Listen 80`

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName web.chipman.local
    ServerAlias www.web.chipman.local
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/site1

    ErrorLog /srv/www/logs/errors.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/logs/access.log common

    <Directory /srv/www/site1>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Перегружаем апач, в случае если сработало, эту строчку переносим в файл ports.conf (Если он есть и подгружается, не обязательно, просто для структуризации) потом опять перегружаем апач